# How to send email alert to all recipients stored in a database using php Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was trying to send job alert to all registered email addresses stored in my database. I retrieved all ID, first_name and email in Model and sent to Controller in which I put into a loop and send to the respective recipients, but unfortunately it doesn't work as I wish to..
Here is my code below:

CONTROLLER code:

```
$get_recipient = $this->job_seekers_model->get_all_recipients_email();
foreach ($get_recipient as $first_name=>$email)
{
    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject($email_subject);
    $mail_message = $this->email_drafts_model->send_message_job_alerts($row_email->content, $row->job_title, $row->job_slug, $row);
    $this->email->message($mail_message);
    $this->email->send();
}
```

MODEL code:

```
public function get_all_recipients_email() 
{
    $this->db->select('ID','first_name', 'email');
    $this->db->from('pp_job_seekers');
    $this->db->where('send_job_alert','yes');
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't send the email alert to the recipients

Comment: Does sending it to a single user work?

Comment: no it doesn't work... please help

Comment: Check if you can send an email with the `mail` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php . If that doesn't work your mail server is not configured/installed properly.

Comment: From your model - are you expecting just one row or many rows?

Comment: You need to learn to use var_dump or print_r to examine your variables/arrays so you can see what is going on...

Comment: if i put email addresses manually without retrieving from the database it works: i tried this $this->email->to('first@gmail.com, second@gmail.com'); without calling Model's function it sends to the mail..

Comment: In model I expect many rows as it has to send to different recipients...

Comment: I replaced $this->db->select('ID','first_name', 'email'); with $this->db->select('ID, first_name, email'); used print_r and it displays all correct values from db..

Answer (score 0):

You're only returning a single entry from your model:

```
 $return = $Q->row();
```

You want them all:

```
$return  = $Q->result(); //or result_array()
```

Better to just `return` vs declaring a variable as I initially thought it must be a typo.

```
foreach($result as $person){
    $this->email->to($person->email); // if you returned an object, $person['email'] for array
}
```